# How to retrieve private posts from Blogger with Service Account using Google Blogger API v3?

Tags: c#, blogger, service-accounts

Using [Google.Apis.Blogger.v3](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/getting_started) is it possible to retrieve posts from a ***private*** blog via a Service Account?

Because the blog is private an [API Key](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#APIKey) alone is not appropriate.  User based [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) consent screens are also not acceptable as the solution is required to be non-interactive server to server.

Tests with ***public*** blogs are successful however tests to ***private*** blogs return errors such as (c# web application):

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
We're sorry, but the requested resource could not be found. [400]
Errors [Message[We're sorry, but the requested resource could not be found.] 
Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global]]
```

I have tried adding the **Service Account ID** email address to the authorized *authors* and/or *readers* however there is no obvious means to *accept the invitation*.

No documentation prohibiting this method of access has been located.

Is this scenario possible?

Answer (score 0):

Retrieval a list of a post from private blog is not possible if you've hide your blog from Blogger listing by activating the setting located in **Settings > Basic > Privacy > Add your blog to our listings?**.

I've also encountered the same problem and currently waiting for the **cache** to be gone and be available on Blogger blog list again. It's been more than 24 hours and still waiting.